# Hibernate mapping json to dto?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use Hibernate and I have a sql

```
SELECT category, 
 json_agg(json_build_object('id', id, 'name', name)) as role 
FROM table 
GROUP BY category;
```

postgres answer:

```
category | CAR
role     | [{"id" : 8, "name" : "BMW"}]
```

My dto java class:

```
public interface System  {
  String getCategory();
  List<Role> getRole();
}

public interface Role {
    Long getId();
   String getName();
}
```

I have a custom Query, when I call it from the controller, an error is thrown.

```
        @Query(value = "SELECT category, 
         json_agg(json_build_object('id', id, 'name', name)) as role 
        FROM table 
        GROUP BY category;", nativeQuery = true)
Collection<System> getSystem();
```

Error:
**org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111**

***Please tell me how to make a mapping?***

Comment: Do you have to do it with Hibernate, or would another approach using other libraries work for you as well?

Comment: I need Hibernate or JDBC. What suggestions do you have?

Comment: [jOOQ](https://jooq.org) can do this out of the box, but if you need Hibernate, I guess you'll need to write a user type and result transformer?

Comment: "you need to write a user type and a result converter" but how do you do that? I read all over the internet and couldn't find a solution! Found guys with a similar problem, but all the questions are unanswered.

Comment: Well, I haven't done this in a while, so I can't tell you off the top of my head. I only know a few off-topic answers, which include what I've mentioned, or maybe use Jackson or Gson to marshal the JSON document into your DTOs